# Expectation of Sums of Squares

Tags: self-study, anova, expected-value, sums-of-squares

$\mu$=mean, $\sigma$=standard dev

show that if $H_0:\mu_1=...=\mu_k$ in the normal one way classification then

the Total Sum of Squares has expectation $E(T)=(N-1)\sigma^2$

the Within Groups Mean Square has expectation $E(W/(N-k))=\sigma^2$

and hence that
the Between Groups Mean Square has expectation $E(B/(k-1))=\sigma^2$

I understand the definitions of each of them but i am completely unsure about how to go about getting the expectation. I assume then i will just be algebraic manipulation.

Comment: Welcome to CrossValidated. If you want good answers, you should show people here what you have tried yourself. Also, most people don't appreciate the imperative form...

Comment: i have no idea to how to start to get the expectation, im pretty sure once i know that i can do it myself

Comment: if you have data $(x_i,y_i)$, $i=1,...,n$, with $x_i$ being the observed value and $y_i$ being the group, then the total sum of squares is $T=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(x_i-\bar{x}\right)^2$.

Comment: Your question is very verbose; which might make it hard for people to figure out what is going on.

Comment: I edited it, I feel it is quite clear.